# PHP JSON No response code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Can anyone help with how to trouble shoot this response from my ajax call?

```
       var dashboardReq = $.ajax({
        url: apiPath + 'dashboard_mobile.php?token=' + token + '&format=json'
        //dataType: 'json'
    });
```

It keeps coming back with:

```
      dashboardReq.error(function(data, jqxhr) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(jqxhr);
    });
```

And below is what I get. I've successfully logged in using the apiPath already at this stage and the token sends fine, but nothing returns.

The error simply says: "error", finding it really hard to troubleshoot.

Any thoughts?

```
Object {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
abort: function (e){var t=e||T;return l&&l.abort(t),k(0,t),this}
always: function (){return i.done(arguments).fail(arguments),this}
complete: function (){if(u){var t=u.length;(function i(t){b.each(t,function(t,n){var r=b.type(n);"function"===r?e.unique&&p.has(n)||u.push(n):n&&n.length&&"string"!==r&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?o=u.length:r&&(s=t,c(r))}return this}
done: function (){if(u){var t=u.length;(function i(t){b.each(t,function(t,n){var r=b.type(n);"function"===r?e.unique&&p.has(n)||u.push(n):n&&n.length&&"string"!==r&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?o=u.length:r&&(s=t,c(r))}return this}
error: function (){if(u){var t=u.length;(function i(t){b.each(t,function(t,n){var r=b.type(n);"function"===r?e.unique&&p.has(n)||u.push(n):n&&n.length&&"string"!==r&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?o=u.length:r&&(s=t,c(r))}return this}
fail: function (){if(u){var t=u.length;(function i(t){b.each(t,function(t,n){var r=b.type(n);"function"===r?e.unique&&p.has(n)||u.push(n):n&&n.length&&"string"!==r&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?o=u.length:r&&(s=t,c(r))}return this}
getAllResponseHeaders: function (){return 2===x?a:null}
getResponseHeader: function (e){var t;if(2===x){if(!c){c={};while(t=Tn.exec(a))c[t[1].toLowerCase()]=t[2]}t=c[e.toLowerCase()]}return null==t?null:t}
overrideMimeType: function (e){return x||(p.mimeType=e),this}
pipe: function (){var e=arguments;return b.Deferred(function(n){b.each(t,function(t,o){var a=o[0],s=b.isFunction(e[t])&&e[t];i[o[1]](function(){var e=s&&s.apply(this,arguments);e&&b.isFunction(e.promise)?e.promise().done(n.resolve).fail(n.reject).progress(n.notify):n[a+"With"](this===r?n.promise():this,s?[e]:arguments)})}),e=null}).promise()}
progress: function (){if(u){var t=u.length;(function i(t){b.each(t,function(t,n){var r=b.type(n);"function"===r?e.unique&&p.has(n)||u.push(n):n&&n.length&&"string"!==r&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?o=u.length:r&&(s=t,c(r))}return this}
promise: function (e){return null!=e?b.extend(e,r):r}
readyState: 0
responseText: ""
setRequestHeader: function (e,t){var n=e.toLowerCase();return x||(e=v[n]=v[n]||e,y[e]=t),this}
state: function (){return n}
status: 0
statusCode: function (e){var t;if(e)if(2>x)for(t in e)m[t]=[m[t],e[t]];else N.always(e[N.status]);return this}
statusText: "error"
success: function (){if(u){var t=u.length;(function i(t){b.each(t,function(t,n){var r=b.type(n);"function"===r?e.unique&&p.has(n)||u.push(n):n&&n.length&&"string"!==r&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?o=u.length:r&&(s=t,c(r))}return this}
then: function (){var e=arguments;return b.Deferred(function(n){b.each(t,function(t,o){var a=o[0],s=b.isFunction(e[t])&&e[t];i[o[1]](function(){var e=s&&s.apply(this,arguments);e&&b.isFunction(e.promise)?e.promise().done(n.resolve).fail(n.reject).progress(n.notify):n[a+"With"](this===r?n.promise():this,s?[e]:arguments)})}),e=null}).promise()}
__proto__: Object
```

This is only happening when trying to bundle in appMobi.

I can run everything fine on localhost (xampp) and also live on the web, by just using a browser.

The php file ends with:

```
    /* output in necessary format */
    if($format == 'json') {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

Comment: what is the response code you are getting

Comment: This looks like [SOP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) to me

Comment: look at actual request in console...net or network tab..can see exactly what is sent and what is returned  ...if actually receiving json paste it into jsonlint.com and make sure it's valid. Also does url print json properly when open in browser? Since is a GET can copy json straight from there

Comment: no response code back at all.

"This request has no response data available"

Comment: @Solvision: and the http response status is?

Comment: is `apiPath` on another domain? ...if so, read link @Musa provided

Comment: Response seems to be: "cancelled", (if that is what you mean, apologies for noviceness)

yes it would be i guess. As appMobi runs off localhost:58888, on the device or emulator.

Answer (score 0):

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

For mobile development on desktop.

I have todo this when i'm doing phonegap stuff so might be the same problem for you.